# Referencing a UDK Class without its source

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I'd like to modify an existing UDK game, but to do this I need to make a subclass of their custom classes. e.g.

```
MyBroadcastHandler extends RX_BroadcastHandler
```

Unfortunately I can't find a single way to do this without having the source code to RX_BroadcastHandler. Otherwise the compiler will complain that RX_BroadcastHandler is not a known type. Is there any way at all to have the compiler reference the .u file with this class instead of requiring the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I'd suggest implementing the prototypes of what you need for each class you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I’m wrong here.

But sounds to me you are trying to implement code that you don’t have and expect it to Work?

If I’m right then I’m sorry but that will never, the compiler can't find it unless you have it in the source directory and added as a package in the DefaultEngineUDK.ini file. And if you don’t have the files have nothing to add to the source file.

If you have the code however then it might be a problem with the build order in the  DefaultEngineUDK.ini file.

E.G.
 my gamegun extend UTgun then inside the  DefaultEngineUDK.ini

The UTGame has to be before the Mygame folder so that the UT game it builds and ready then I start Building the mymgame content.
Like this.

[UnrealEd.EditorEngine]

+EditPackages=UTGame

+EditPackages=MYgame

Hope this helps to point you in the right direction, it is all I can do with the info you gave :)